# How to make an open source fork derived from closed source project?

Tags: git

I am forking part (but not all) of a closed source project to make an open source one. So far I have made a branch ('open') from which I have removed the features we're *not* going to open source.

Now I could at this point export the 'open' branch and check it in to a fresh, empty repo, which becomes the open source release.

However, I would like to maintain ability to sync changes between the open and closed source versions: i.e. if we later fix a bug in the closed source, then sync the fix to the open source version also (and vice versa if the contributor consents).

Is there a way I can achieve this, without making the history of the 'open' branch (i.e. the closed branch) public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As git stores commits as change sets, you can easily cherry-pick changes of one repo to another (if of course the same changed files are present and they don't differ too much).

One way to accomplish this is by adding both "origin"s as remote to a single repo clone.
Then fetching all commits from both remotes (so you have the commit hashes available).
You can then check out one remote's branch and cherry-pick the other remote's commit just like any other single-remote repo cherry-pick.

Something like this in a terribly construed example:

```
git clone git://blablabla.git mydoublerepo
cd mydoublerepo
git remote add other git://other.git
git fetch other
git checkout -b other_master -t other/master
git cherry-pick origin/master # cherry-picks the top commit off of the other remote's master branch
```

Note you don't need to create a separate clone for this, you can add any repo as a remote to any other cloned repo.